# Enumerating with a for-in loop

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a loop that's throwing an error "Int is not convertible to Range< Int >":

```
var summaryValues:[Int]=[Int]();
for (dayIndex,valuesPerDay) in enumerate(allValuesPerDay){
    if (valuesPerDay>0){
        while summaryValues[dayIndex]==nil{ // ERROR
            summaryValues.append(0);
        }
        summaryValues[dayIndex]++
    }
}
```

That fourth line should simply  be checking if there is a value at `summaryValues` in position `dayIndex`, but I'm a little unclear on the Swift syntax. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

The work-around I've implemented is to replace the error line with
`while cohortRetension.count<dayIndex+1` but I'd still like to better understand why `summaryValues[dayIndex]` was incorrect.

Comment: How allValuesPerDay is coming ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `allValuesPerDay` is of type `[Int]`

Comment: what you are trying to achive with dayIndex its little bit unclear . can you tell me actully how you want to solve your case ? what should be your final out come ?

Comment: Here's an example: on the third iteration of the loop, `dayIndex` will equal 2. In that iteration, I'd like to check if the third element of `summaryValues` (i.e., `summaryValues[2]`) is initialized, or whether it should be set to 0.

Comment: compare dayIndex to summaryValues.count

Comment: @WillM. Hey Will, thank for the comment. I just actually swapped out that line to use `count`, but I still don't understand the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> while summaryValues[dayIndex]==nil{ // ERROR

summaryValues is an array and array[i] won't return nil. It will either return the element or it will crash if your index is out of range. First, the compiler is probably confused from comparing `Int` and `nil`. Second, trying to access `summaryValues[dayIndex]` here will crash, because at the time you are checking it the array is empty and the index does not exist.

Comment: OK, great. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly appending to an array is inappropriate when you know the size up front.  Initialize your `summaryValues` as:

```
var summaryValues = [Int](count: allValuesPerDay.count, repeatedValue: 0)
```

then iterate over your `allValuesPerDay` simply with:

```
for dayIndex in 0..<allValuesPerDay.count { 
   if allValuesPerDay[dayIndex] > 0 {
      summaryValues[dayIndex]++
   }
}
```